# Error using DocuSign AuthenticationApi.login() for Legacy Authentication - Missing grant_type/code

Tags: java, docusignapi, oltu

I'm trying to use the Authentication::login() API call in the DocuSign Java SDK and am receiving an error.  Here's some code:

```
@Component
public class TestClass {

    private ApiClient apiClient;

    public void authenticate() {

        this.apiClient = new ApiClient("account-d.docusign.com", "docusignAccessCode",
                "mySecretIntegratorKey", "myClientSecret");

        final AuthenticationApi authenticationApi = new AuthenticationApi(this.apiClient);

        try {
            // ERROR ON THE LINE BELOW
            final LoginInformation loginInformation = authenticationApi.login();
        } catch (final ApiException e) {
            // do something appropriate
        }
    }
}
```

The `mySecretIntegratorKey` and `myClientSecret` values are not the real values I'm sending in obviously, but the other ones are.

Here is the error I am receiving when making the login() call:

```
Caused by: org.apache.oltu.oauth2.common.exception.OAuthSystemException: Missing grant_type/code
at com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth$OAuthJerseyClient.execute(OAuth.java:184)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:65)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:55)
at org.apache.oltu.oauth2.client.OAuthClient.accessToken(OAuthClient.java:71)
at com.docusign.esign.client.auth.OAuth.updateAccessToken(OAuth.java:92)
... 123 common frames omitted
```

I realize that this is using the older legacy authentication, however I have a limitation that won't allow me to upgrade to the newer method of authentication until the first of the year.  So for now I need to use this legacy method using SDK Version 2.2.1.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?  I'm sure it is something simple...

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Legacy authentication?

In that case you need to make a number of updates to your code.

- Only call `new ApiClient(base_url)`
- Set the X-DocuSign-Authentication header--

From an [old Readme:](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/72ff53079f13df2124fa359cf4b41a007d2dcbc0/README.md)

```
String authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" +  username +
   "\",\"Password\":\"" +  password + 
   "\",\"IntegratorKey\":\"" +  integratorKey + "\"}";
apiClient.addDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
```

- Then use the `authenticationApi.login` to look up the user's Account ID(s) and matching base urls.

The `authenticationApi.login` doe **not** actually log you in. (!)

Rather, that method just gives you information about the current user.

There is no login with the API since it does not use sessions. Instead, credentials are passed with *every* API call. The credentials can be an Access Token (preferred), or via Legacy Authentication, a name / password / integration key triplet.

When using Legacy Authentication, the client secret is not used.

More information: see the Readme section for using username/password in this [old version of the repo.](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/tree/72ff53079f13df2124fa359cf4b41a007d2dcbc0)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I had searched for documentation specifically to use the legacy authentication but came up dry; that link to the old ReadMe was huge!  I now have it working with the legacy authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone was looking for complete legacy code that works! The below C# code snippet works. This is production ready code. I've tested it and it works. You will have to create an EnvelopeDefinition separately as this code is not included. However, the piece below will authenticate the user and will successfully send an envelope and get back the Envelope ID:

```
string username = "john.bunce@mail.com"; 
string password = "your_password"; 
string integratorKey = "your_integration_key"; 

ApiClient apiClient = new ApiClient("https://www.docusign.net/restapi");

string authHeader = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";

apiClient.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader);
AuthenticationApi authApi = new AuthenticationApi(apiClient.Configuration);

LoginInformation loginInfo = authApi.Login();

string accountId = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].AccountId;
string baseURL = loginInfo.LoginAccounts[0].BaseUrl;
string[] baseUrlArray= Regex.Split(baseURL, "/v2");   

ApiClient apiClient2 = new ApiClient(baseUrlArray[0]); 
string authHeader2 = "{\"Username\":\"" + username + "\", \"Password\":\"" + password + "\", \"IntegratorKey\":\"" + integratorKey + "\"}";

apiClient2.Configuration.AddDefaultHeader("X-DocuSign-Authentication", authHeader2);        

EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient2.Configuration);

EnvelopeSummary results = envelopesApi.CreateEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDefinition);
string envelopeID = results.EnvelopeId;
```